# regular expression in python [to get text after number phone]

Tags: python, regex

I have a little worry with my regular expressions. I would like to retrieve all the texts that come after the phone number to each.The text is as follows:

---

> 22/06/2018 à 10:16 PM - Les messages envoyés dans ce groupe sont
>   désormais protégés avec le chiffrement de bout en bout. Appuyez pour
>   plus d'informations.
>
> 28/05/2018 à 4:34 PM - ‎‪+60 17-751 1232‬ a créé le groupe
>   "SE&E(SEE)Asia✈⛴Travelers group"
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:16 PM - Vous avez intégré le groupe en utilisant le
>   lien d'invitation
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:17 PM - Kdm: I need help i want to travel to China. so
>   i need visa  can i help me about information
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:17 PM - Kdm: Hey everyone
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:18 PM - ‪+62 857-1592-9544‬: yes, you can help
>   yourself
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:19 PM - Kdm: Lol
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:20 PM - ‪+91 96500 52277‬: Where do u wantbto go in
>   chian ?
>
> 22/06/2018 à 10:21 PM - Kdm: Capital because i have a problem with my
>   passport . So i want to apply for a new passport ; am student in hanoi

---

```
match = re.search(r'((?:\+|00)[17](?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)[1-9]\d{0,2}(?: |\-)?|(?:\+|00)1\-\d{3}(?: |\-)?)?(0\d|\([0-9]{3}\)|[1-9]{0,3})(?:((?: |\-)[0-9]{2}){4}|((?:[0-9]{2}){4})|((?: |\-)[0-9]{3}(?: |\-)[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{7}))(.*?)\s(.*)',splitstring[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

are you set on using regular expressions? if not another way you could find just the text after the sender is:

```
# coding=utf-8

position_of_character = newline.find(': ')
print newline[position_of_character+1:]
```

This piece of code will find the colon with one space after it.
This will specifically then pull values for the second colon in each line of text and ignore the colon found in the time stamp.
However, it isn't necessarily foolproof, since there may be messages that contain ': ' in them.

Answer (score 0):

This regex captures everything after the phone number/name of the recipient -  letters, numbers and emoticons;

```
r': (.+)'
```

[Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/XK0BYH/8)

However as Cici mentioned, there may be messages that contain ': ' in them, which it would also capture.